# CakePHP. How can i make a model test in a table with another primary key?

Tags: sql, testing, cakephp, primary-key, auto-increment

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE myexamples.problems (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  pk_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

But when I try test a model in cakephp, it fails because the table has two autoincrement attributes. The following query

```
CREATE TABLE `test_suite_problems` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pk_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pk_id`)
)
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1, COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci, ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

raise this error:

```
"1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"
```

I have in the model class

```
<?php
class Problem extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Problem';
    var $displayField = 'name';
    var $primaryKey='problems';
}
?>
```

But I don't know how to make the field ID not having an autoincrement attribute, and I can't change the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a field named "problems". So this is one issue. Your PK seems to be pk_id so set the correct field name for primaryKey.

The other one is not a CakePHP issue:

```
1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

This is a SQL error. You cant have two auto incrementing fields. Change your fixture to match your real table schema which has not two auto incrementing fields.

Your database schema is not following CakePHPs conventions. Follow the conventions and you get  a lot less problems and benefit from the "auto-magic" of the framework. I guess you tried to bake the fixtures but cake could not recognize the correct fields because you do not follow the conventions.

Comment: Yes, the $primaryKey=problems was a mistake when i copy this here, i had $primaryKey = pk_key. 
Finally i identify the problem. When problem_fixture.php is created with bake, is there where the var $fields has two fields with auto_numeric, the "id" field and the "pk_id field". I delete there the autonumeric in id, and each when update it, and work without problem

Comment: This is exactly what I've told you.